# Create a border that uses the windows theme

Tags: wpf, xaml, border

I want to create a border in WPF (XAML) that uses the colors from the current windows theme (XP, Areo, Classic, Modern UI).

I have already tried to use some Brushes from the `SystemColors` class but the border is not looking the same as the default border of a `TextBox`.

Is there any way to get the real brush of the borders?

Comment: This location http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=wpfsamples&DownloadId=7812 contains the templates for the default WPF controls and should give you the proper brushes to use.

Answer (score 3):

Given below is the default style used by WPF for the `TextBox` control:

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation"
            Value="None" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
            Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth"
            Value="120" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight"
            Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop"
            Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
          <Border Name="Border"
                  CornerRadius="2"
                  Padding="2"
                  BorderThickness="1">
            <Border.Background>
              <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
            </Border.Background>
            <Border.BorderBrush>
              <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource BorderMediumColor}" />
            </Border.BorderBrush>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
              <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                      (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                      <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                           Value="{StaticResource DisabledControlLightColor}" />
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                      (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                      <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                           Value="{StaticResource DisabledControlDarkColor}" />
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
              </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <ScrollViewer Margin="0"
                          x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
          </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```